# Is there a difference between calling the 'where' function in the beginning of the query and in the end in terms of performance?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Sorry if this is too obvious, I was wondering is there a difference between the two blocks of code below in terms of performance and amount of data retrieved?
 will specifying the id in the end of the query (like in `FirstOrDefaultAsync(b => b.BuyModelId == modelId)`) brings all the table data first and then evaluate it against the id?

and will calling the `Where` function in the beginning (like this `Where(b => b.BuyModelId == modelId)`) will evaluate the data against the id and then call the include functions ?

So to summarize my question: is there a specific order to which those statements execute?

because I was worried that there might be some extra overhead in my calls to the database.

```
public async Task<BuyModel> GetModelById(int modelId)
{
    return await _applicationDbContext.BuyModels
         .Where(b => b.BuyModelId == modelId)
         .Include(b => b.Buyer)
         .Include(b => b.ItemsToBuy).ThenInclude(p => p.Category)
         .Include(b => b.ItemsToBuy).ThenInclude(p => p.SalesUser).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

```
public async Task<BuyModel> GetModelById(int modelId)
{
    return await _applicationDbContext.BuyModels
         .Include(b => b.Buyer)
         .Include(b => b.ItemsToBuy).ThenInclude(p => p.Category)
         .Include(b => b.ItemsToBuy).ThenInclude(p => p.SalesUser).FirstOrDefaultAsync(b => b.BuyModelId == modelId);
}
```

Comment: check generated sql in console log and compare them. I think it would be same.

Comment: There should be no difference. But you can easly check the [generated SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412863/how-do-i-view-the-sql-generated-by-the-entity-framework)

Comment: Even if the generated SQL is different (unlikely) the execution plan that the DB uses will likely be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is zero difference. Until the queryable is evaluated (using something like `ToListAsync`), everything just goes to constructing a SQL query that will *eventually* be sent.

That said, the latter version is preferred, since it's more clear what you're querying.

Answer (score 2):

As said in the comments, there are two layers to performance of LINQ-to-entities query.

First is what SQL is generated. In your scenario, I would guess that they will be the same. Only way to be sure is to have EF output the generated SQL.

If the generated SQL are different, then SQL can still create same execution plan. SQL server has lots of cleverness and magic when it comes to optimizing queries. There is big chance that both queries would result in same execution plan and thus same performance.

But if you really care about performance, you should really analyze both the generated SQL query and how SQL runs this query. Preferably on full and index-enabled one, so that execution plan is realistic.